# ifeq doesn't compare two variable

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

ifeq doesn't compare two variable

I'm making a program to move a file to the desktop, independently of the language chosen in the OS. In portuguese the desktop folder is called "Área de trabalho". Since "Área de Trabalho" are three separated words, you need to add single quotation marks ('Área de Trabalho') when writting the directory, otherwise the command results in error.

```
    mv Minesweeper $HOME/Área de Trabalho/  #command

    mv: target 'Trabalho/' is not a directory  #Error
```

I'm using this command to get the directory of the desktop folder of the user:

```
    xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
```

And if the directory is equals to the home directory plus "/Área de Trabalho", I want to change

Here's the code:

```
    desktop=$(shell xdg-user-dir DESKTOP) # I'm using this command to get the directory of the desktop folder of the user
    desktopVar="$$HOME/Área de Trabalho" # And if the directory is equals to the home directory plus "/Área de Trabalho"

    move:
    ifeq (${desktop},${desktopVar})
        desktop=${HOME}/'Área de Trabalho' # I want to change the directory to ${HOME} plus "/'Área de Trabalho'", so the command doesn't results in error
        @echo yes
    endif
        @echo ${desktopVar}
        @echo ${desktop}
```

But the ifeq says both variables are equal and doesn't change anything.

Here's the output:

```
    /home/daniel/Área de Trabalho
    /home/daniel/Área de Trabalho
```

Comment: Rule 1: Never add `@` to your recipe lines until after your entire makefile is completely working (and maybe not even then).  Rule 2: Never use a recipe or shell to print make variables, because the shell interprets the contents and could change the results before they are printed.  Always use make's `$(info ...)` function so you can see exactly what make sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a makefile that should work (no, really this time :-) I actually tested this one:)

```
desktop:=$(shell xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)
desktopVar:=${HOME}/Área de Trabalho  #note: using _MAKE_ variable ${HOME} here

$(info desktop:     [${desktop}])
$(info desktopVar:  [${desktopVar}])

    # note: using double quotes around ifeq arguments -- not required
    #       here, but it's good practice:
    # also note: this is not inside of a recipe, so it's done by the
    #            makefile at parse time

ifneq ("${desktop}","${desktopVar}")
$(info changing desktop)
desktop:=${HOME}/Área de Trabalho
endif


$(info desktop:     [${desktop}])
$(info desktopVar:  [${desktopVar}])

all:
        @echo running $@
```

which outputs:

```
scripts> make -f test.mk
desktop:     [/users/foo/Desktop]
desktopVar:  [/users/foo/Área de Trabalho  ]
changing desktop
desktop:     [/users/foo/Área de Trabalho]
desktopVar:  [/users/foo/Área de Trabalho  ]
running all
```

Comment: I tried this makefile and it didn't work :(    I noticed the { ") } in the end of this line:  desktopVar=${HOME}/Área de Trabalho")      I tried also removing it and also writing it on the other side and the makefile still aren't working :(

Comment: Oops, cut a and paste.   Did you remove the bracket?   I'll add some debugging code in there that might help.

Comment: I just ran the above.   Also the `ifeq` should have been `ifneq`.   In the sample above I switched to using `:=`, but it shouldn't make a difference for your case

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes are part of the variable value, but they aren't shown in the output because the shell interprets them.

```
desktop = a
desktopVar = "a"

test:
ifeq ($(desktop),$(desktopVar))
    @echo yes
else
    @echo no
endif
    echo $(desktop)
    echo $(desktopVar)
```

So, the solution is to include the double quotes in the definition:

```
desktop = "$(shell xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"
```

Don't overuse `@`, seeing what Makefile actually tries to run can often help you when debugging.

Comment: I included the double quotes as you said and also deleted the last two @. Here's the new output:´        echo "$HOME/Área de Trabalho"´
´        /home/daniel/Área de Trabalho´
´        echo "/home/daniel/Área de Trabalho"´
´        /home/daniel/Área de Trabalho´

Comment: Yes, the double dollar sign is causing you isssues.   As far as make is concerned, one variable contains `$HOME/Area de Trabalho`, and the other `/home/daniel/Area de Trabalho`, which are different strings.   When make passes the `$HOME` string to bash, _bash_ expands the `$HOME` to `home/daniel`, and thus the prints are the same.   (But the ifdef is in make, where the expansion hasn't happened yet....)

Comment: Also, asigning the variable `desktop` in a recipe doesn't do what you think it does -- it sets a _bash_ variable for that particular recipe line.   It won't effect the make variable.   It also will be forgotten once that recipe line terminates...